Blazor syncfusion Filemanager
I just started using syncfusion and I find myself in trouble for the FILEMANAGER, basically I followed the guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcH3B8FTPao following step by step but in the end I receive an error NetworkError:Failed to send on XMLHTTPRequest:Failed to load https://localhost:7225/api/FileManager/FileOperations searching on vai forum it would seem that the problem is baseurl but I can't find a solution, is there anyone who has already had

the same error and found the solution?
my code is following
FileManagerController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


using Syncfusion.EJ2.FileManager.Base;
using Syncfusion.EJ2.FileManager.PhysicalFileProvider;

namespace LawSync.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public class FileManagerController : Controller
    {
       
            string basePath;
            PhysicalFileProvider operation;

            public FileManagerController(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
            {
                basePath = hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
                operation = new PhysicalFileProvider();
                operation.RootFolder(basePath + "\\Data\\Files");
            }
        
        [Route("FileOperations")]
            public object FileOperations([FromBody] FileManagerDirectoryContent args)
            {
                switch (args.Action)
                {
                    // Add your custom action here
                    case "read":
                        // Path - Current path; ShowHiddenItems - Boolean value to show/hide hidden items
                        return this.operation.ToCamelCase(this.operation.GetFiles(args.Path, args.ShowHiddenItems));
                    case "delete":
                        // Path - Current path where of the folder to be deleted; Names - Name of the files to be deleted
                        return this.operation.ToCamelCase(this.operation.Delete(args.Path, args.Names));
                    case "copy":
                        //  Path - Path from where the file was copied; TargetPath - Path where the file/folder is to be copied; RenameFiles - Files with same name in the copied location that is confirmed for renaming; TargetData - Data of the copied file
                        return this.operation.ToCamelCase(this.operation.Copy(args.Path, args.TargetPath, args.Names, args.RenameFiles, args.TargetData));
                    case "move":
                        // Path - Path from where the file was cut; TargetPath - Path where the file/folder is to be moved; RenameFiles - Files with same name in the moved location that is confirmed for renaming; TargetData - Data of the moved file
                        return this.operation.ToCamelCase(this.operation.Move(args.Path, args.TargetPath, args.Names, args.RenameFiles, args.TargetData));
                    case "details":
                        // Path - Current path where details of file/folder is requested; Name - Names of the requested folders
                        return this.operation.ToCamelCase(this.operation.Details(args.Path, args.Names));
                    case "create":
                        // Path - Current path where the folder is to be created; Name - Name of the new folder
                        return this.operation.ToCamelCase(this.operation.Create(args.Path, args.Name));
                    case "search":
                        // Path - Current path where the search is performed; SearchString - String typed in the searchbox; CaseSensitive - Boolean value which specifies whether the search must be casesensitive
                        return this.operation.ToCamelCase(this.operation.Search(args.Path, args.SearchString, args.ShowHiddenItems, args.CaseSensitive));
                    case "rename":
                        // Path - Current path of the renamed file; Name - Old file name; NewName - New file name
                        return this.operation.ToCamelCase(this.operation.Rename(args.Path, args.Name, args.NewName));
                }
                return null;
            }

            [Route("Download")]
            public IActionResult Download(string downloadInput)
            {
                FileManagerDirectoryContent content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileManagerDirectoryContent>(downloadInput);
                return operation.Download(content.Path, content.Names);
            }


            [Route("Upload")]
            public IActionResult Upload(string path, IList<IFormFile> uploadFiles, string action)
            {
                FileManagerResponse uploadResponse = operation.Upload(path, uploadFiles, action, null);
                if (uploadResponse.Error != null)
                {
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    Response.StatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(uploadResponse.Error.Code);
                    Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = uploadResponse.Error.Message;
                }
                return Content("");
            }

            [Route("GetImage")]
            public IActionResult GetImage(FileManagerDirectoryContent args)
            {
                return operation.GetImage(args.Path, null, false, null, null);
            }
        
    }
}




and blazor page is next
@page "/Test"
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.FileManager
@* @rendermode InteractiveServer *@


<SfFileManager TValue="FileManagerDirectoryContent">
    <FileManagerAjaxSettings Url="/api/FileManager/FileOperations"
                             DownloadUrl="/api/FileManager/Download"
                             UploadUrl="/api/FileManager/Upload"
                             GetImageUrl="/api/FileManager/GetImage">
    </FileManagerAjaxSettings>
</SfFileManager>


Thank you

